# crear algoritmo para conocer N numeros primos sin usar mod %

Tags: algoritmos, pseint, pseudocódigo

Alguien sabe como mejorar el código, sin usar mod% ni trunc ?

Algoritmo este_si
escribir " ingrese cuantos numeros desea consultar"
leer numeros
acum<-0

```
para i<-1 Hasta numeros Con Paso  1 hacer 
    acum<-0
    para j<-1 hasta i Con Paso 1 hacer 
        resultado = i / j
        si resultado - trunc(resultado) == 0 Entonces
            acum = acum + 1
        FinSi
    FinPara
    
    si acum == 2 Entonces
        escribir i, " Es primo"
    SiNo
        Escribir i, " no es Primo"
    FinSi
FinPara
```

FinAlgoritmo

Comment: Necesitas la operación de módulo/resto para saberlo. La única alternativa es crear tu propia implementación para esta operación. Es más cómodo dejarle al procesador hacerlo por hardware que por software.

Comment: como substituto % puedes usar en caso d'enteros (a-(a/b)*b) de lo cual (a/b) tiene que convertirse en entero y a es el numerador y b es el denominador

Comment: Yo te recomendaría usar la [criba de Eratóstenes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes), que no usa la operación módulo y suele ser más rápido que comprobar la primalidad de cada número.

Answer (score -1):

podrías hacer con divisibilidad,
por ejemplo no existen primos pares aparte del 2.
si la suma de las cifras es múltiplo de tres no es primo pues es divisible por 3.
si termina en 5 o 0 es múltiplo de 5 lo cual no es primo.
revisa las demás reglas de divisibilidad.
un número primo no es mayor que su raíz cuadrada, luego se debe mirar la divisibilidad entre 1 y la raíz del número que se desea saber si es primo.

aunque sin mod es mucho más difícil y largo, podría ser un buen ejercicio de programacion sin funciones.